# Ruby on Rails: How to generate Tests for a Plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following the Ruby on Rails [guide for creating Plugins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html), and I've been having trouble generating even the First test the Tutorial requires. Taken from the Tutorial:

[image: Tutorial 1st Test]

To me this means creating a test with a generator like this?:

```
yaffle $ rails g test core_ext
```

But that **doesn't work**, Can anybody please explain to me,

**How should I generate tests for a Ruby on Rails plugin?**

I'm aware a plugin comes with a *dummy app* under the */test Dir* itself(From which you can actually issue rails commands), **but** notice the Tutorial shows that the test file is created under project_root(yaffle)/test and Not under project_root(yaffle)/test/dummy/test/

I'm really confused about this, How do I actually generate the test(s) this tutorial requires?

Thanks in advance for the explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no generator for tests. You run `rake test` from the root and write the tests manually.

The tutorial tells you where to make the test file, what to name it, and what code to put in it:

```
# yaffle/test/core_ext_test.rb
# This is the location and name of the test file^
# Everything below this line is what you put in core_ext_test.rb

require 'test_helper'

class CoreExtTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_to_squawk_prepends_the_word_squawk
    assert_equal "squawk! Hello World", "Hello World".to_squawk
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I was beginning to suspect that's the case. However it's a bit confusing because a plugin comes with an 'internal' rails app within; in which you can run generators for tests.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that's the case. The dummy app should behave more or less like a regular Rails app, and in my experience I've never seen a generator for creating tests in Rails standard. There are test cases for creating generators, and you could probably write a generator to make tests, but I'm pretty certain nothing like that exists in standard rails.

If you know of any test generators, please share them with me.

Answer (score 0):

"How should I generate tests for a Ruby on Rails plugin?"

When you run the plugin generator, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/plugins.html, the associated test files are also created.  However, if it did not, below is how you can create them manually.

In the root of the `test` directory, you need at least two files.

A `test_helper.rb`. this is a bootstrap for executing tests.  By default, this should already exist for you. My setup allows test to be executed from the rails app as well ( dummy/ ) if you have any there too. Notice, I am also loading fixtures for the dummy rails app too. There is one change from the default Yaffle example due to a Rails4 bug ( see comment inline ).

```
 # Configure Rails Environment
 ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"

 require File.expand_path("../dummy/config/environment.rb",  __FILE__)
 require "rails/test_help"

 Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!

 # Load support files
 Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }
 Dir.glob("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/dummy/app/models/*.rb").sort.each { |file| require_dependency file }

 # see https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4971 for why we cant test this method
 #if ActiveSupport::TestCase.method_defined?(:fixture_path=)
 ActiveSupport::TestCase.fixture_path = File.expand_path("../dummy/test/fixtures", __FILE__)
 #end

 # Load fixtures from the engine
 class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  set_fixture_class :users => "User"

  fixtures :all
 end
```

your `yaffle_test.rb` can be a very simple truth test initially

```
 require 'test_helper'

class YaffleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   test "Yaffle is a module" do
     assert_kind_of Module, Yaffle
   end
end
```

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if your answer is accurate, My question is more aimed towards knowing if it's possible to use a rails generator FROM the project's root to create the test file(s) automatically (without having to make dirs/files manually), Do you know if this is possible?
Thank you for your reply, sir.

Comment: Hi JoseE, when you run `rails plugin new yaffle` this should have created core_ext tests from what the docs say.  However, I notice that instead it creates `test/yaffle_test.rb` which is the equivalent as far as I can tell.  Did this file exist after you ran the initial generator for the plugin?